# Convert Long to Timestamp in Hive

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I want to store start time of spark application into table. Hence tried following code:

```
scala> val i = sc.startTime
i: Long = 1519308048128
```

This query along gives proper timestamp in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:M:SS.sss`. But if I use it in insert statement with `spark.sql` , `NULL` values get inserted into target table.

```
spark.sql("
  insert into table TST_DT
  select from_unixtime(CAST(${i}/1000 AS bigint),'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS') 
  from temp limit 1")
```

Target able `TST_DT` has only only column with data type `Timestamp`

I tried using `cast` function in hive, still result is same :-

```
spark.sql("
  insert into table TST_DT
  select cast(from_unixtime(CAST(${i}/1000 AS bigint),'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS') 
  as timestamp) from temp limit 1")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your date format string is incorrect. Refer to [SimpleDataFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```scala
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(sc.startTime/1000)).toDF("ts")

df.withColumn("ts" , from_unixtime($"ts" , "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS") ).show(false)
+-----------------------+
|ts                     |
+-----------------------+
|2018-02-22 05:35:19.000|
+-----------------------+

df.withColumn("ts" , from_unixtime($"ts" , "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS") ).show(false)
+-----------------------+
|ts                     |
+-----------------------+
|2018-02-53 05:02:00.000|
+-----------------------+
```

All's well till now because `from_unixtime` returns a string. But as soon as you cast it to `timestamp`:

```scala
df.withColumn("ts" , from_unixtime($"ts" , "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS") )
  .selectExpr("cast(ts as timestamp)").show
+-------------------+
|                 ts|
+-------------------+
|2018-02-22 05:35:19|
+-------------------+

df.withColumn("ts" , from_unixtime($"ts" , "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS") )
  .selectExpr("cast(ts as timestamp)").show
+----+
|  ts|
+----+
|null|
+----+
```